# How can I call a PHP function with some of the values from an array?

Tags: php, function, arguments

Given the function `bar` takes a variable number of arguments. How can `foo` be implemented?

```
function foo($a, $b, $c) {
    return bar($a, $b, $c[0], $c[1], $c[2], ..., $c[n]);
}
```

Comment: `function foo($arrParams)` is not possible?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like homework, plus there must be a duplicate question regarding PHP and variable number of function arguments

Comment: It's not homework. When I ask questions I remove everything that might confuse the matter.

Comment: If this is a duplicate please link to the other question so that people can find the other question and vote to close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) allows you to call a function with an array of parameters. Create the parameter array and call the function:

```
$parameters = array_merge(array($a, $b), $c);
return call_user_func_array('bar', $parameters);
```

Comment: [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fdEKZ2) of hakre's method with an implementation of `bar()` and `foo()`.